# SQL cross table SELECT sum() for each item in another SELECT

Tags: sql

I have two SQL tables: `ProductsCatalog` and `OrdersCatalog`.

`ProductsCatalog`:

```
id, barcode(unic), name, quantity
```

`OrdersCatalog`:

```
id, barcode(non-unic), ordered
```

Each product can be ordered several times. I need to compose single SQL request that returns all products from `ProductCatalog` with the actual information about products remaining.

Pseudo-code:

```
products = SELECT (barcode,name,quantity) FROM ProductsCatalog;
foreach(product in products){
  product.quantity -= SELECT sum(ordered) FROM OrdersCatalog WHERE barcode = product.barcode;
}
```

Is this possible using only SQL requests without server code? Is this possible using a NoSQL database like Amazon dynamoDB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this. IFNULL works in mysql, with SQL Server use ISNULL function. If you return any error please comment this and I'll correct. I can't try the solution in this moment.

```
SELECT PC.barcode, 
       pc.name, 
       PC.quantity - Sum(Ifnull(OC.ordered, 0)) AS COLUMN_NAME 
FROM   productscatalog PC 
       LEFT JOIN orderscatalog OC 
              ON PC.barcode = OC.barcode 
GROUP  BY PC.barcode, 
          pc.name, 
          PC.quantity
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great (postgresql, IFNULL function not needed).
Only one detail appears: how to rename _?column?_ in result?

Comment: @cyberXndr just edited reply with AS COLUMN_NAME. Ifnull or Isnull or any other test is needed in case you have no orders for the product in OrdercsCatalog.